# Object navigation disappeared - How to get it back?

Tags: objects, navigation

I was following along this tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QAGpxV36wM and got to the 10 minute mark, and just learned about object duplication and snap to grid (To stack some cubes). Somehow, the object move arrows disappeared and I can't move my objects around without them. Anyone know the secret? I'm using blender 3.6.5 on win7 64 bit.

I clicked the appropriate "object move" button on the left toolbar (3rd button from the top) and still don't see them when selecting the object. The object rotation capability also disappeared, don't see the encircling lines to rotate the object.

ANSWER: I found the real answer is I had to press escape. I did press escape as the video instructed, and that must've somehow disabled the object navigation; looks like pushing the ESC button brought back the object navigation arrows. The "Duplicate post" linked to does not contain this answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.